# FactoryGirl HABTM transactional_fixtures produce MissingAttributeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, transactions, has-and-belongs-to-many

I got an error with rspec and HABTM relation when the system try to rollback the data.

Here is my rspec configuration :

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

And a very dummy HABTM relation :

```
# == Schema Information
# Table name: permission
#  id            :integer          not null, primary key
#  name          :string
#  subject_class :string
#  action        :string
#  description   :text
class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :admin_roles
end

# == Schema Information
# Table name: admin_role_permission
#  permission_id :integer
#  admin_role_id :integer
class AdminRolePermission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :admin_role
  belongs_to :permission
end

# == Schema Information
# Table name: admin_role
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  title      :string
class AdminRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :permissions
end
```

I have the base FactoryGirl file created and the following test :

```
RSpec.describe "Check that factories are removed after each test" do

  it 'minimal test' do
    admin_role  = FactoryGirl.create(:admin_role, title: 'admin_role')
    permission  = FactoryGirl.create(:permission, name: 'test')
    FactoryGirl.create(:admin_role_permission, permission: permission, admin_role: admin_role)
    expect(AdminRole.count).to eq(1)
  end
end
```

This produce me this error :

```
F

Failures:

  1) Check that factories are removed after each test minimal test
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError:
       can't write unknown attribute ``
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute.rb:124:in `with_value_from_database'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_set.rb:39:in `write_from_user'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:74:in `write_attribute_with_type_cast'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:56:in `write_attribute'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:92:in `write_attribute'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:393:in `restore_transaction_record_state'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:324:in `rolledback!'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:73:in `rollback_records'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:151:in `rollback'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:183:in `rollback_transaction'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:221:in `rollback_transaction'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:961:in `block in teardown_fixtures'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:960:in `each'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:960:in `teardown_fixtures'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:830:in `after_teardown'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-rails-3.2.1/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in <module:MinitestLifecycleAdapter>'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:333:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:333:in `instance_exec'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:387:in `execute_with'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247:in `call'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:247:in `call'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:617:in `run_around_example_hooks_for'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:474:in `run'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:343:in `with_around_example_hooks'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:385:in `with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:174:in `run'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:548:in `block in run_examples'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:544:in `map'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:544:in `run_examples'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:512:in `run'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:110:in `block (3 levels) in run_specs'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:110:in `map'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:110:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1526:in `with_suite_hooks'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:109:in `block in run_specs'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:62:in `report'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:108:in `run_specs'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
     # /Users/sylvestre/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

And if I turn use_transactional_fixtures = false. It's work (but it persist the created factory)

How can I make work the previous code using the transactional_fixtures?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain that this is the cause of your problem, **BUT** it probably is.

When you use `habtm` you should **NOT** have a model for the association itself. Your join table should also not have a primary key (`id`) field.

Probably the error you're getting is somehow related to the fact that you have an intermediate model and probably you have a primary key in your join table.

#### Two Choices

The options you have are:

1. Fix the habtm by removing the `AdminRolePermission` model and migration, and creating a new migration for your `admin_roles_permissions` table (notice the pluralization in there) and [as detailed in the docs for habtm](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many) make sure you have `id: false` in there, or...
2. Leave everything as it is and use `has_many :through` instead of `habtm`, it does add some burden for the creation of objects (because you'll need to actually create the join table model).

#### Fingers Crossed

Your app won't work anyway as it is right now so you have to do one of the above options anyway, but hopefully fixing that also fixes your test problem.